# Auto completion with the BotFramework's WebChat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I want auto completion on my BotFramework's WebChat, I can use [flexdatalist](http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/) to implement this functionality on `<input>` tags, but how can I change the SendBox's properties ?

Here is an example of how flexdatalist works:

```html
<input 
  type='text'
  placeholder='Type your message...'
  class='flexdatalist'
  data-data='link/to/json'
  data-search-in='name'
  data-visible-properties='["name","intent"]'
  data-selection-required='true'
  data-min-length='1'
  name='suggest_questions'
/>
```

The result is [here](https://ibb.co/Bnm0yD6)

The dev team are currently working on a "auto-complete box" (source: [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1551#issuecomment-451236327)), progression can be tracked [on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/476)

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but a user in GitHub said they were indeed able to accomplish this with flexdatalist https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/476#issuecomment-469556894 maybe try to reach out to them if possible.

Comment: @D4RKCIDE I sent a message to the discussion, and I linked it to my original post so everyone can track improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to combine React, which WebChat is written in, and JQuery since React won't recognize any changes made by JQuery. That being said, you can add flexdatalist to WebChat's input field, but you also have to dispatch actions to WebChat's store to notify it of changes. See the code snippets below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>One Bot to Rule Them All</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <link href="/jquery-flexdatalist-2.2.4/jquery.flexdatalist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/jquery-flexdatalist-2.2.4/jquery.flexdatalist.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>


    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { 
        margin: 0;
       }

      #webchat,
      #webchat > * {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

    <script>

      (async function() {

        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3978/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token }  = await res.json();

        const store = window.WebChat.createStore({},
            ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
              if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
                // Clear the input field when the message is sent
                $("input[data-id='webchat-sendbox-input']").val("")
              }
          return next(action);
        });        

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
        store,
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

      $("input[data-id='webchat-sendbox-input']").flexdatalist({
        minLength: 1,
        searchIn: 'name',
        data: 'countries.json'
      });

      $("input[data-id='webchat-sendbox-input']").on('select:flexdatalist', (event, set, options) => 
        store.dispatch({ 
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX', 
          payload: { 
            text: set.name
          }
        })
      );

      $("input[data-id='webchat-sendbox-input']").on('change:flexdatalist', (event, set, options) => {
          console.log(event)
          store.dispatch({ 
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX', 
            payload: { 
              text: set.value
            }
          })
        }
      );

      })().catch(err => console.log(err));

    </script>
  </body>
```

Note, following this approach disables sending a message when the user presses enter, so the user has to press the send button. Unfortunately, I could not find a functional workout for that.

Hope this helps!