# How to implement AutoComplete Text view in an adaptive card

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, adaptive-cards

I have a use case in which i have to show responses from an API to the user, as he types in the text view in the adaptive card, I have a Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework, my chat bot is currently working in a web client, but i want this functionality to also work on Microsoft Teams and other platforms (in which adaptive card is supported). Adaptive Card doesn't support AutoComplete view, its in there roadmap for now.

So here i am looking for a workaround to implement this functionality in my Bot.

Answer (score 1):

If your main use case is Teams, then you have another option, but it will work **only** in Teams - it is to use a Task Module. Basically, Task Modules are a special kind of popup window in Teams. You have two options for what gets shown in a Task Module:

1. An Adaptive Card
2. Any custom web page, that is basically just being IFramed into the popup

So, you could look at using option 2 above, building anything you want into the web page, including "autocomplete". Later, if / when Adaptive Cards offers what you need, you could simply change out what gets shown to the user, from being your custom web page, to being the Adaptive Card.

You can read more about Task Modules, and how to get started, at [What are Task Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules).

Of course, as I said, Task Modules only work in Teams, so it won't help your other scenarios, but perhaps you can use the regular Adaptive Cards there, and do the Task Module if you detect the client is using Microsoft Teams.

Comment: my first priority is web client, but i want my solution to be generic enough to work on cross platform like Microsoft Teams.

Comment: ah ok. No other ideas my side then I'm afraid.  Let me know if you do decide to go with the Task Module for Teams at least, and need any help

Answer (score 0):

Although Adaptive Cards do not support autocomplete view as of now, instead of using Adaptive Cards, you can build our own component and use attachmentMiddleware to intercept those cards. You can add an input field with your autocomplete logic in your custom renderer.

- Refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.custom-components/e.card-components) sample for the implementation of the above logic.

Code Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Custom attachment with GitHub Stargazers</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.6/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@7.1.0/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
     const GitHubRepositoryAttachment = props =>
       <div style={{ fontFamily: '\'Calibri\', \'Helvetica Neue\', Arial, sans-serif', margin: 20, textAlign: 'center' }}>
         <svg height="64" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="64" aria-hidden="true"><path fillRule="evenodd" d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"></path></svg>
         <p>
           <a href={ `https://github.com/${ encodeURI(props.owner) }/${ encodeURI(props.repo) }` } target="_blank">{ props.owner }/<br />{ props.repo }</a>
         </p>
       </div>;

      (async function () {

        const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token } = await res.json();
        const { ReactWebChat } = window.WebChat;
       const attachmentMiddleware = () => next => card => {
         switch (card.attachment.contentType) {
           case 'application/vnd.microsoft.botframework.samples.github-repository':
             return <GitHubRepositoryAttachment owner={ card.attachment.content.owner } repo={ card.attachment.content.repo } />;

           default:
             return next(card);
         }
       };

        window.ReactDOM.render(
          <ReactWebChat
           attachmentMiddleware={ attachmentMiddleware }
            directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }) }
          />,
          document.getElementById('webchat')
        );

        store.dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
          payload: { text: 'sample:github-repository' }
        });

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Also, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56079912/auto-completion-with-the-botframeworks-webchat/56085249#56085249) SO answer on **Autocompletion with Botframework's Web Chat** where you can add flexdatalist to WebChat's input field, but you also have to dispatch actions to WebChat's store to notify it of changes.

Hope this helps.